# The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable Spark app error

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hdfs

I have created a Spark application which uses Hive metastore but in the line of the external Hive table creation, I get such an error when I execute the application (Spark driver logs):

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwxrwxr-x;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:102)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwxrwxr-x
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.newState(HiveClientImpl.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

I run the application using the Spark operator for K8s.
So I checked the permissions of the directories ob driver pod of the Spark application:

```
ls -l /tmp
...
drwxrwxr-x    1 1001     1001          4096 Feb 22 16:47 hive
```

If I try to change permissions it does not make any effect.
I run Hive metastore and HDFS in K8s as well.

How this problem can be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common error which can be fixed by creating a directory at another place and pointing the spark to use the new dir.

**Step 1:** Create a new dir called tmpops at `/tmp/tmpops`

**Step 2:** Give permission for the dir `chmod -777 /tmp/tmpops`
        Note:  -777 is for local testing. If you are working with sensitive data make sure to add this path to security groups to avoid accidental data leakage and security loophole.

**Step 3:** Add the below property in your hive-site.xml that the spark app is referring to:

```
  <property>
    <name>hive.exec.scratchdir</name>
    <value>/tmp/tmpops</value>
  </property>
```

Once you do this, the error will no longer appear unless someone deletes that dir.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue in window 10, below solution helped me to get this fixed.

Following steps solved my problem

1. Open Command Prompt in Admin Mode
2. winutils.exe chmod 777 /tmp/hive
3. Open Spark-Shell --master local[2]